# Can you define a complex Typescript return type inline (without an explicit interface)?

Tags: typescript

I've got a typescript method that returns a structured object:

```
export interface LoginResult{
  success:Boolean,
  message:String
}

login():LoginResult{
  ...
  // do login logic
  return {
    success: successVal,
    message: messageVal
  }
}
```

Rather than having to define the interface distinctly though I would like to be able to simply define the return type inline as part of the method call, something like the following:

```
login():LoginResult:{success:Boolean, message:String}{
  ...
  // do login logic
  return {
    success: successVal,
    message: messageVal
  }
}
```

Is this possible and if so what is the correct syntax?

Comment: You can just do `login(): { success: boolean, message: string } { ... }`, but you can't then *name* the type.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: That is an answer and should be posted as such -_-

Comment: @Peter Nixey also pay attention to difference between `boolean` and `Boolean` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#general-types

Comment: thanks all - @jonrsharpe if you'd like to post as an answer I'll accept and Aleksey, good heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer from @jonrsharpe above:

You can just do `login(): { success: boolean, message: string } { ... }` but you can't then *name* the type